# Wrong voltage out of ST LE33: 1V instead of 3.3V

Tags: ldo

I got an ST LE33 and I am providing +5V between pin 2 and pin 3 as per [specs](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/98/09/12/54/6e/d1/45/36/CD00000545.pdf/files/CD00000545.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000545.pdf). Checked with a multimeter.

I am reading +1V between pin 1 and pin 2, without any load, no capacitors. If I put a 1MOhm resistor, the voltage drops a bit.

I took a picture of the guy in case the shop sent me the wrong item, but it reads LE33.

Am I doing something wrong?

[image: ST LE33]

Comment: Are you using the correct input and output capacitors? And what if you use a larger load like a 3k resistor for 1 mA draw.

Answer (score 3):

> no capacitors

> Am I doing something wrong?

No capacitors.

Capacitors are required. See fig. 3 of the spec sheet: 100 nF across input, 2.2 uF across output.

> I am providing +5V between pin 2 and pin 3

Just to make sure it's clear: pin 1 is the left-most pin in the picture you provided.